# Personalizar cores no ionic6

Tags: ionic, aplicação-web, framework

Amigos e amigas recentemente iniciei meus estudos no Ionic e de cara já comecei na versão mais atual (6.4.2)

Estou com uma dificuldade tamanha que começo a questionar minha inteligência. (risos)

Estou tentando fazer algo simples como alterar a cor de um componente. Já tentei alterar o app.component.scss incluindo uma instrução igualmente simples como:

```
:root {
    --ion-background-color: #ff3700;
}
```

Já tentei incluir uma cor seguindo a documentação do Ionic incluindo no (nome da minha page).page.scss:

```
:root {
  --ion-color-teste: #2B4A42;
  --ion-color-teste-rgb: 43,74,66;
  --ion-color-teste-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-teste-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-teste-shade: #26413a;
  --ion-color-teste-tint: #405c55;
}

.ion-color-teste {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-teste);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-teste-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-teste-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-teste-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-teste-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-teste-tint);
}
```

Ai no meu HTML apenas incluo esta cor em um componente como um "ion-button", também seguindo um exemplo da documentação do Ionic

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors

```
<ion-button color="teste">Teste</ion-button>
```

Mas por algum motivo extremamente estranho nada funciona. Já finalizei o serve e iniciei novamente.

Já tentei de tudo mas não consigo criar ou alterar cores no Ionic.

Desde já agradeço imensamente pela atenção e auxílio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estilizar componentes no Ionic pode ser de fato uma tarefa curiosa.

Mas todos os componentes do Ionic tem "CSS Custom Properties" definidos pelo próprio time do Ionic. Na versão 5 eles aparecem mais ao final da documentação de cada componente.

Para o `ion-button` temos [essas propriedades](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties)

```css
ion-button {
  --background: red;
}
```

```html
<ion-button>
  Algum texto
</ion-button>
```